# How to parametrize Linux kernel boot to entirely miss any video?

Tags: linux, boot

I am trying to boot a linux kernel without switching to any vga mode. So, I only want the character display. Can I somehow do that? Actually, some like a `vga=off` or similar would be pretty okay.

Comment: (My current goal is to boot it in qemu with the "curses" display backend. But anyways the question is only, is it possible to turn off this vga/kms thing in the linux kernel with boot arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the kernel to *not* change video modes by adding [the `nomodeset` parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

> Disable kernel modesetting. Most systems' firmware
> sets up a display mode and provides framebuffer memory
> for output. With nomodeset, DRM and fbdev drivers will
> not load if they could possibly displace the pre-
> initialized output. Only the system framebuffer will
> be available for use. The respective drivers will not
> perform display-mode changes or accelerated rendering.